# Dynamically created radio button is disappearing while clicking

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting the all views but when I click the button and scroll down at that time the it will be unchecked. I added the removeall views on the `onBindViewHolder`. because the radiobuttons are generated infinite times. Here I shared the code please check it.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.radioGrp.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL)
    holder.radioGrp.removeAllViews()
    holder.bindView(position)
}

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val radioGrp = itemView.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radio_group)

    fun bindView(position: Int) {
        itemView.tv_question.text = feedback[position].questions
        var newAnswer = feedback[position].answser as ArrayList<String>

        if (newAnswer.isEmpty()) {
            itemView.linear2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            newAnswer.forEach {
                itemView.linear2.visibility = View.GONE
                val rb = RadioButton(context)
                rb.text = it
                rb.id = position
                radioGrp.addView(rb)

                rb?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { 
                  buttonView, isChecked ->
                    if (isChecked) {
                        rb.isChecked = true
                        examinationListener.addAnswer(names)
                    } else {
                        rb.isChecked = false
                        examinationListener.removeAnswer(names as String)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track the checked state of your answers externally to the views and apply the state when binding the views. Assuming the answers for each list item are all unique Strings, you could use a Map to store the states.

```
// In your adapter:
val answerStates = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableMap<String, Boolean>>()

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val radioGrp = itemView.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radio_group)

    fun bindView(position: Int) {
        itemView.tv_question.text = feedback[position].questions
        val newAnswer = feedback[position].answser as ArrayList<String>


        if (newAnswer.isEmpty()) {
            itemView.linear2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            itemView.linear2.visibility = View.GONE

            // Lazily create answer states map for this list item
            val answerStates = answerStates[position] 
                ?: mutableMapOf<String, Boolean>().also { answerStates[position] = this }

            newAnswer.forEach {
                val rb = RadioButton(context)
                rb.text = it
                rb.id = position
                rb.checked = answerStates[it] ?: false // Bind last known state, default false
                radioGrp.addView(rb)

                rb?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { 
                  buttonView, isChecked ->
                    answerStates[it] = isChecked // Save state
                    if (isChecked) {
                        rb.isChecked = true
                        examinationListener.addAnswer(names)
                    } else {
                        rb.isChecked = false
                        examinationListener.removeAnswer(names as String)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your data can change, this gets more complicated. You would need to store this Boolean in your actual Feedback class so it can be restored when there is fresh data.

Comment: But sometimes the radio button is automatically checked  while scrolling up and down